# Dragon programming language on termux

Tags: termux

Recently i checked out the Dragon programming language. I dont have pc.then i want to install it on termux.
But the process which is shown on their site which is too old
" https://dragon-language-projects.github.io/android-installation/ "

Thats why its not installing its shell file. Its installing its html file of site whenever i tried this

`wget https://dragon-lang.org/installdragon && bash installdragon`
Can anybody solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any updates of Dragon language for Termux. Maybe the Termux version is discontinued. I rather suggest you to use Dragonoid app. It's an Android Compiler for Dragon programming language.

Comment: But it had lots of bugs